# Get information API JSON in android studio(JAVA) OR org.json.JSON.typeMismatch / org.json.JSONException Errors

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-studio

I have been working on an android project in which I want to fetch the breed of dogs from an API (JSON format). I have created layout and basically all the animation stuff.
In the main activity I have include the animation and splash screen and in second activity I am working with the API. I have did so far:

**API:** https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all

JSON format looks something like this:
[image]

```
package com.example.dogsbreedapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import java.net.URL;

public class DogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();

                while(data!=-1)
                {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Log.i("JSON DATA!!!", s);
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

                String breedInfo = jsonObject.getString("message");
                Log.i("BREED INFO !-->>",breedInfo);

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(breedInfo);

                for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonPart = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("Breed->1",jsonPart.getString("australian"));
                    Log.i("Breed->2",jsonPart.getString("buhund"));
                    Log.i("Breed->3",jsonPart.getString("bulldog"));
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dog);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all");
    }
}
```

I am quite confident with my code but unable to understand where am I going wrong.

**LogCat:**
[image]

Please do help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this line `String breedInfo = jsonObject.getString("message");`
`message` is actually a JsonObject instead of String, so it throw a TypeMismatchError as you can see in the log.

I tried the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String apiResponse = "{\"message\":{\"affenpinscher\":[],\"african\":[],\"airedale\":[],\"akita\":[],\"appenzeller\":[],\"australian\":[\"shepherd\"],\"basenji\":[],\"beagle\":[],\"bluetick\":[],\"borzoi\":[],\"bouvier\":[],\"boxer\":[],\"brabancon\":[],\"briard\":[],\"buhund\":[\"norwegian\"],\"bulldog\":[\"boston\",\"english\",\"french\"],\"bullterrier\":[\"staffordshire\"],\"cairn\":[],\"cattledog\":[\"australian\"],\"chihuahua\":[],\"chow\":[],\"clumber\":[],\"cockapoo\":[],\"collie\":[\"border\"],\"coonhound\":[],\"corgi\":[\"cardigan\"],\"cotondetulear\":[],\"dachshund\":[],\"dalmatian\":[],\"dane\":[\"great\"],\"deerhound\":[\"scottish\"],\"dhole\":[],\"dingo\":[],\"doberman\":[],\"elkhound\":[\"norwegian\"],\"entlebucher\":[],\"eskimo\":[],\"finnish\":[\"lapphund\"],\"frise\":[\"bichon\"],\"germanshepherd\":[],\"greyhound\":[\"italian\"],\"groenendael\":[],\"havanese\":[],\"hound\":[\"afghan\",\"basset\",\"blood\",\"english\",\"ibizan\",\"plott\",\"walker\"],\"husky\":[],\"keeshond\":[],\"kelpie\":[],\"komondor\":[],\"kuvasz\":[],\"labradoodle\":[],\"labrador\":[],\"leonberg\":[],\"lhasa\":[],\"malamute\":[],\"malinois\":[],\"maltese\":[],\"mastiff\":[\"bull\",\"english\",\"tibetan\"],\"mexicanhairless\":[],\"mix\":[],\"mountain\":[\"bernese\",\"swiss\"],\"newfoundland\":[],\"otterhound\":[],\"ovcharka\":[\"caucasian\"],\"papillon\":[],\"pekinese\":[],\"pembroke\":[],\"pinscher\":[\"miniature\"],\"pitbull\":[],\"pointer\":[\"german\",\"germanlonghair\"],\"pomeranian\":[],\"poodle\":[\"miniature\",\"standard\",\"toy\"],\"pug\":[],\"puggle\":[],\"pyrenees\":[],\"redbone\":[],\"retriever\":[\"chesapeake\",\"curly\",\"flatcoated\",\"golden\"],\"ridgeback\":[\"rhodesian\"],\"rottweiler\":[],\"saluki\":[],\"samoyed\":[],\"schipperke\":[],\"schnauzer\":[\"giant\",\"miniature\"],\"setter\":[\"english\",\"gordon\",\"irish\"],\"sheepdog\":[\"english\",\"shetland\"],\"shiba\":[],\"shihtzu\":[],\"spaniel\":[\"blenheim\",\"brittany\",\"cocker\",\"irish\",\"japanese\",\"sussex\",\"welsh\"],\"springer\":[\"english\"],\"stbernard\":[],\"terrier\":[\"american\",\"australian\",\"bedlington\",\"border\",\"dandie\",\"fox\",\"irish\",\"kerryblue\",\"lakeland\",\"norfolk\",\"norwich\",\"patterdale\",\"russell\",\"scottish\",\"sealyham\",\"silky\",\"tibetan\",\"toy\",\"westhighland\",\"wheaten\",\"yorkshire\"],\"vizsla\":[],\"waterdog\":[\"spanish\"],\"weimaraner\":[],\"whippet\":[],\"wolfhound\":[\"irish\"]},\"status\":\"success\"}";

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(apiResponse);

        JSONObject breedInfo = jsonObject.getJSONObject("message");
        Log.i("BREED INFO !-->>",breedInfo.toString());
        List<String> resultList = new LinkedList<String>();
        Iterator<String> breedKeys = breedInfo.keys();
        while (breedKeys.hasNext()){
            JSONArray breedArray = breedInfo.getJSONArray(breedKeys.next());
            for(int i = 0; i<breedArray.length();i++ ){
                resultList.add(breedArray.getString(i));
            }
        }
        Log.i("Result!-->>",resultList.toString());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
2021-05-09 16:27:25.552 7225-7225/com.example.java I/BREED INFO !-->>: {"affenpinscher":[],"african":[],"airedale":[],"akita":[],"appenzeller":[],"australian":["shepherd"],"basenji":[],"beagle":[],"bluetick":[],"borzoi":[],"bouvier":[],"boxer":[],"brabancon":[],"briard":[],"buhund":["norwegian"],"bulldog":["boston","english","french"],"bullterrier":["staffordshire"],"cairn":[],"cattledog":["australian"],"chihuahua":[],"chow":[],"clumber":[],"cockapoo":[],"collie":["border"],"coonhound":[],"corgi":["cardigan"],"cotondetulear":[],"dachshund":[],"dalmatian":[],"dane":["great"],"deerhound":["scottish"],"dhole":[],"dingo":[],"doberman":[],"elkhound":["norwegian"],"entlebucher":[],"eskimo":[],"finnish":["lapphund"],"frise":["bichon"],"germanshepherd":[],"greyhound":["italian"],"groenendael":[],"havanese":[],"hound":["afghan","basset","blood","english","ibizan","plott","walker"],"husky":[],"keeshond":[],"kelpie":[],"komondor":[],"kuvasz":[],"labradoodle":[],"labrador":[],"leonberg":[],"lhasa":[],"malamute":[],"malinois":[],"maltese":[],"mastiff":["bull","english","tibetan"],"mexicanhairless":[],"mix":[],"mountain":["bernese","swiss"],"newfoundland":[],"otterhound":[],"ovcharka":["caucasian"],"papillon":[],"pekinese":[],"pembroke":[],"pinscher":["miniature"],"pitbull":[],"pointer":["german","germanlonghair"],"pomeranian":[],"poodle":["miniature","standard","toy"],"pug":[],"puggle":[],"pyrenees":[],"redbone":[],"retriever":["chesapeake","curly","flatcoated","golden"],"ridgeback":["rhodesian"],"rottweiler":[],"saluki":[],"samoyed":[],"schipperke":[],"schnauzer":["giant","miniature"],"setter":["english","gordon","irish"],"sheepdog":["english","shetland"],"shiba":[],"shihtzu":[],"spaniel":["blenheim","brittany","cocker","irish","japanese","sussex","welsh"],"springer":["english"],"stbernard":[],"terrier":["american","australian","bedlington","border","dandie","fox","irish","kerryblue","lakeland","norfolk","norwich","patterdale","russell","scottish","sealyham","silky","tibetan","toy","westhighland","wheaten","yorkshire"],"vizsla":[],"waterdog":["spanish"],"weimaraner":[],"whippet":[],"wolfhound":["irish"]}

2021-05-09 16:27:25.558 7225-7225/com.example.java I/Result!-->>: [shepherd, norwegian, boston, english, french, staffordshire, australian, border, cardigan, great, scottish, norwegian, lapphund, bichon, italian, afghan, basset, blood, english, ibizan, plott, walker, bull, english, tibetan, bernese, swiss, caucasian, miniature, german, germanlonghair, miniature, standard, toy, chesapeake, curly, flatcoated, golden, rhodesian, giant, miniature, english, gordon, irish, english, shetland, blenheim, brittany, cocker, irish, japanese, sussex, welsh, english, american, australian, bedlington, border, dandie, fox, irish, kerryblue, lakeland, norfolk, norwich, patterdale, russell, scottish, sealyham, silky, tibetan, toy, westhighland, wheaten, yorkshire, spanish, irish]
```